# Spilt sentence to array of words keep fomat

Tags: java, regex

I wanna spilt a sentence to a array of words
e.g.

```
Hello this a sentence
this is a new line
```

I used `String[] arr = String.spilt(str)`
but when i wanna combine array to sentence the result is:

```
Hello this a sentence this is a new line
```

So how i can split string keep new line characters?
Thank you!

Comment: Unless you're using a new line symbol `\n` you can't retain line breaks. If you have `\n` for sentences then you can store that in the array and read for it, to split the sentence.

Comment: There's no static `String.spilt` method. I'm assuming you never actually tried that code?

Comment: use list of array.One array per line.Number of elements in list==number of lines :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split takes regular expression,

split("(?=\n)")

This will preserve the \n

Provided your string contains \n

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    String str= "Hello this a sentence \n this is a new line";
    System.out.println(str);
    String[] xyz = str.split("(?=\n)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(xyz));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a new line

you should use any special character when you make string i.e.

string str = "Hello this a sentence" +"\n"+ "this is a new line"

Then split your string on the base of special character i.e.
string[] arr = str.split("\n");